# Using Drupal 7 Ubercart - how can I make 'create order' apply taxes?

Tags: 7, ubercart

When an admin creates an ubercart order from the backend, taxes are not applied. Does anyone have a suggestion as to how to make this happen? Through the drupal interface, or if a custom module, which hook or function does this? I have tried a few already...

Comment: This issue is discussed on the drupal.org - https://www.drupal.org/project/ubercart/issues/1425978